# Instrument approach DME VS instrument approch ILS DME

Tags: approach

what is the diffrence of Instrument Approach DME and Instrument Approach ILS DME?
Is it same as LOC DME APCH and ILS DME APCH?

Answer (score 2):

The name for each approach indicates what equipment is required, so DME, ILS/DME and LOC/DME would all be different--and some aircraft may be able to fly one but not another.  Generally, the better (i.e. more precise) the equipment available, the lower the minimums can be because the obstacle clearance area will be smaller.